# Update EndPoints Of Web Api On Build Project ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have a React project created with create-react-app, which connects to a web api, this application must be installed on multiple clients locally, so the EndPoints of the API change for each client and to avoid the fact If I have to recompile the project on each client, I would like to be able to have a separate file, where I can change this URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your appSettings.json

Add a new property like `clientName: "client1"`

You will need to change this for every instance of the application you deploy.

Then using your Configuration you can do `private string clientName = Configuration.GetValue("clientName")`

Then add it to the controller route -

```
[Route($"{clientName}\[controller]")]
```

Comment: Hello, the problem is not in the backEnd but in the ReactJs client at the time of installation change update the endpoints, since both the react client and the api are hosted locally.

Comment: I think in that case you will want to make use on environment variables, the documentation here seems comprehensive enough - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: Here is some information on how to use env variables in deployment - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#customizing-environment-variables-for-arbitrary-build-environments